# How to add to a variable every 24 hours in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, time

I'm completely lost in finding a tutorial or some sort of answer.

I'm trying to add a number (**+1** for example), **to a variable** (that gets saved locally), **every** said amount of time (**24 hours**). Even if the user doesn't open/run the app.

**Example:** A mobile game named, "Cookie Clicker", kind of has this same functionality. It gives the user cookies depending on how much time was spent not playing the game/being offline.

**My Question:** How can I add +1 to a variable every 24 hours, regardless of if the user opens the app.

**Code I Currently Have:**

```
let daysOffDesfult = UserDefaults.standard
var daysOff = 0


//After 24 Hours: Call updateDaysOff() Function (This is the code I need.)


//Code Used to Save Variable Locally:
//Display the Updated Variable
if (daysOffDesfult.value(forKey: "daysOff") != nil){
    daysOff = daysOffDesfult.value(forKey: "daysOff") as! NSInteger!
    countLabel.text = "\(daysOff)"
}

//Update the Variable
func updateDaysOff() {
    daysOff = daysOff + 1
    countLabel.text = "\(daysOff)"

    let daysOffDesfult = UserDefaults.standard

     daysOffDesfult.setValue(daysOff, forKey: "daysOff")
     daysOffDesfult.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add one every 24 hours. You simply need to calculate how many days have elapsed when the app is opened. When the app moves to the background save the current date/time in UserDefaults. When the app returns to the foreground or launches, determine the elapsed time and add the right number to your counter

Comment: @Paulw11 Great solution! How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the time of first open app in viewDidLoad or in your first UIViewController in `UserDefaults` like this:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstDate") == nil {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "firstDate")
}
```

and every time app launches you compare the current date to date that you saved in `UserDefaults` to find out how many days passed

```
let savedDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstDate")
let currentDate = Date()
let diffInDays = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: savedDate, to: currentDate).day
```